# How can I store files in Django

Tags: python, html, django

How can I be able to store files in Django in a model?

Well, I know about the FileField but I don't understand how it works the thing is that I want to be able to store the file and no the path cause like I am making a cloud storage website for a project and want to be able to store the file.

And how could I be able to change the file name when a user wants to change it.

Comment: files don't fit within a database unless you intend to bloat it out with the files binary. hence the path. to an actual filesystem

Comment: so like what should I do.

Comment: like should I store the path to file

Comment: so like what happens if I get a file through an input tag (type=file)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to explain simply how it works as it'll help you decide the best solution for you.

1. Local system storage.

You store the path in the database, and set the storage class on the field as, `FileSystemStorage` which means django will know to write and read from the hard disk of the same system your django app is running on. So basically you store normal files with references to their location in a directory.

2. Cloud storage.

Similar to local system, but instead of a local path you save a uri location, and instead of the local system you'll fetch the file over the network either via http, or a custom protocol like s3. In order to achieve this you need to declare a custom storage class, where you define your custom `save` and `delete` methods to upload and delete from your cloud storage.

You can write your own: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/howto/custom-file-storage/

Or use a library: https://github.com/jschneier/django-storages

3. Database storage

If you know files are text, you can read them and save the text directly in the database with associated metadata. If they are binary you can store them as Blob type - the risk here is slow performance and risk of bloating the database. AFAIK it's a better practice to store binaries outside the database.

Comment: And if you can could you explain more the custom storage in Django.
Thank You, Nathan

Comment: The documentation link I posted for writing custom storages does a better job than I could. I recommend you just try and implement one after those examples and you'll begin to understand how it works.